# Parsing nested function body PHP

Tags: php, regex, pcre

i am trying to get this working: It is ment to return any function or method where the different 'functional parts' are subgrouped. I have problems with the maybe nested {..{.{} } } function body. At the moment the search breaks of after the first following  }.

I do have a little bit a hard time understanding lock arround and recursive handling of Regs. So if someone would like to give a brief overall view - would be great!

i understand enough for this..
The Regex:

```
    to work with preg_* in PHP with "/im" set 
    ([\w ]+)?(function)+([\s]+[\w\d]+)([\s]*?\(([^\)]+)?\))([\s]?\{+[^\}]*\})
```

Here a sample of use (i dont have named subpatterns on this sample...):

```
   <?php
    $s=file_get_contents('sometestcode');
    $p='/
    ([\w ]+)?(function)+([\s]+[\w\d]+)([\s]*?\(([^\)]+)?\))([\s]?\{+[^\}]*\})
    /im';
    $m=array();
    preg_match_all($p,$s,$m,PREG_SET_ORDER);
    var_dump($m);
    ?>
```

Here comes the output as expected:

```
    // Here the subject:

    public static private function __set($name,$val){
            $this->DATA[$name] = $val;
            foreach( /*do it*/ ){
               //work it...
            }
            return $this;
    }

    // The return 

        array(6){
        [1]=>
        string(7) "public static private " //makes sence, ha?
        [2]=>
        string(8) "function"
        [3]=>
        string(6) " __set"                 // func/meth name
        [4]=>
        string(12) "($name,$val)"
        [5]=>
        string(10) "$name,$val"            // (if passed)$argument...
        [6]=>
        string(60) "{
            $this->DATA[$name] = $val;
            foreach( /*do it*/ ){
               //work it...
            }
            // Here is the my link
            // How to style the regExpPress??

    }"
```

Comment: post the input and the expected output.

Comment: To handle nested things, one generally has to use a [recursive pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php)

Comment: sorry my connection is very slow, it takes a while for all to be displayed... @Dan YES - i know and this is my problem. dont know how to.... s. a.

Comment: I think there are better tools for this job like [tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php), [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) and especially the [FileReflection](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Code/Reflection/FileReflection.php) class from Zend Framework 2.